# Limits and digit sums

Tags: calculus, number-theory, limits

Let $x\in  \mathbb{N}, f(x)$ - digit sum of $x$ , $f^{[n]}(x)$ - digit sum of digit sum of digit sum of $x$.... ($n$ times)

$radix = 10$

Does this limits for different $n$ exists and if it's true when what they are?

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f^{[n]}(x) $$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f^{[n-1]}(x)}{f^{[n]}(x)} $$

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f^{}(x)}{f^{[n]}(x)} $$

$$n= 1, 2, radix, \infty$$

What if a $radix$ is a prime number? Is it somehow affects to the existence/value of the limit?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)\equiv x\pmod{9}$ (or in generally modulo radix minus one).
For fixed $n$, $f^{[n]}$ becomes arbitrarily large, so the first limit does not exist (not even $\to\infty$, as we have $f(x)=1$ every now and then again).
The second limit does not exist either and even less the last.

Comment: The radix $2$ is a small exception here, since $f^\infty(x)=1$ regardless of the value of $x$. In such case, the first limit exists and is equal to $1$. The second limit also exists for $n$ "equal" to $\infty$ and is trivially equal to $1$.